# Kafka producer messages not showing up in consumer (read via kafka-spark streaming)

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

KAFKA PRODUCER command used :

```
#-> kafka-console-producer --broker-list  brokerhost:9093 --topic testtopic --producer.config client.properties

Hello 

How are you

Bye

Where is my message?
```

Code snippet used by consumer-spark streaming and packaged as jar-

```
        val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("kk-KafkaSparktest")
        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
        val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "brokerhost:9093", 
        "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("testtopic" -> 5))
        lines.print()
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Command used to run the packaged jar–

```
spark-submit --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/KK/kafka/jaas.conf' --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/krb5.conf -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/KK/kafka/jaas.conf' --class main.scala.sparkkafka --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster kafkaproj2_2.10-1.0.jar
```

Output shown on log

```
-------------------------------------------
Time: 1502275406000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1502275408000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1502275410000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
Time: 1502275412000 ms
-------------------------------------------

-------------------------------------------
// no key value pairs here
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to make any changes in my code? I think the expectation is messages in KEY:VALUE pairs but we are seeing nothing here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you try to push in port `9093` and read in `9092`?

first of all check your message is well in kafka : 
 `kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server brokerhost:9093  --topic  testtopic`

Then I think you can found interest in the new APIs called 'structured streaming' added to the spark 2.2: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Comment: thanks for that. I changed the port to match, but still not seeing the key value pair after the timestamp. can u please check and help please.

Answer (score 0):

here some steps :

first, check the if Kafka topic has message or not

kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper  --topic  --from-beginning --property print.key=true --property key.separator=,
                                    --property print.key=true \
                                    --property key.separator=,

if it is printing the message then you have message in kafka, if not not then your producer is not working

try below code if message there in Kafka

```
lines.foreachRDD { rdd =>
// Get the offset ranges in the RDD
val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
for (o <- offsetRanges) {
  rdd.map(x=>x.value().mkString(",")).foreach(println)
  println(s"${o.topic} ${o.partition} offsets: ${o.fromOffset} to 
${o.untilOffset}")
}
}
lines.map(record => record.value().mkString(",")).count()
```

below is a simple command for producer

```
echo '00157,{"name":"xyz", "title":"dev"}' | 
kafka-console-producer.sh \
        --broker-list <brokeer list> \
        --topic <topic name> \
        --property parse.key=true \
        --property key.separator=, \
        --new-producer
```